# Apache не работает модуль rewrite

Tags: apache, rewrite

Не могу понять почему не работает модуль rewrite,
сейчас имеется в конфиге 
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Также сам модуль тоже подключен

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

да и по указанному пути библиотеке есть

.htaccess для теста

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://google.com [R=301,L]
```

Но редирект не происходит, не могу понять в чем проблема
Модуль главное есть в подгрузки
apache2ctl -M

```
    Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Потратил минут 20, пока нашел, почему не работает модуль apache mod_rewrite в Ubuntu 16.04

проверьте в конфигурационном файле /etc/apache2/apache.conf значение директивы AllowOverride

нужно

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

было

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

Предварительно (или потом) нужно включить модуль mod_rewrite командой:

sudo a2enmod rewrite

Проверить подключенные модули можно командой apachectl -M , должно быть что похожее:

core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)

И перезапустить apache:

sudo systemctl restart apache2

Теперь можно настроить перенаправление в файле .htaccess :

## перенаправление всех запросов в файл index.php

```
#разрешаем перенаправление
RewriteEngine on
#записываем базовую папку сайта
RewriteBase /php/
#правило перенаправления
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```